# Airplane status - boarding delayed check in?

Tags: translation

Can someone please help me out? What do the following mean?

1) 过站登机
2) 正在值机

These are found at the airport regarding flight statuses. Does it mean boarding, delayed, check in etc? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is  正在值机? Not 正在登机?

Comment: yeah i copied and pasted straight from the zhengzhou airport website http://www.zzairport.com/

Comment: 过站登机 = pass through station to board (boarding station) ; 正在值机 = Checking-in. I can't believe an airport website doesn't have English version of it. There have to be a link to the English site  somewhere on that page...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

过站登机 transit boarding
The original passengers are boarding now.
过站 is the same as 经停 or 过境.

正在值机 checking in